# Change adjacent div background when hover over :before element

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a step indicator, with a hover effect when hovering over a step.

I have posted a working version here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOoqde?editors=1100

I would like to change the colour of `step-indicator__item-bubble` when a user hovers over `step-indicator__item::before`

I have tried todo something like this around line 33 in the pen

```
   &:hover::before {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
   &:hover::before &-bubble {
      background: red;
    }
```

However this does not work.

How can I target the background colour of the bubble div, when hovering over the `::before` of the parent div?

Comment: You can’t, that’s not possible. You will need to find a different structure to achieve what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated that's not possible with your current structure.

I would approach this something like...

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li>1
    <div class='bubble'></div>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="active">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li:hover .bubble {
  display: block;
}

li .bubble {
  display: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -5px;
}

li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: dodgerblue;
  z-index: -1;
}

li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightblue;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightblue;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

Which should give you the same effect[image]